# JAGS: prior's distribution inside a distribution

Tags: bayesian, apriori, jags, rjags

This is our first model:

```
# Data:
x1 = as.factor(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
x2 = as.factor(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))
x3 = as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
x4 = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
n = rep(1055, 16)
y = c(239, 31, 15, 11, 7, 5, 18, 100, 262, 32, 38, 32, 8, 7, 16, 234)

# Model:
mymodel = function(){
  for (i in 1:16){
    y[i] ~ dbin(theta[i], n[i] )
    eta[i] <- gamma*x1[i]+beta1*x2[i]+beta2*x3[i]+beta3*x4[i]
    theta[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-eta[i]))
  }

  # Prior
  gamma ~ dnorm(0,0.00001) 
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
  beta2 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
  beta3 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
}
```

Now we are asked to add alpha as a Normal, with known mean and unknown variance. But the variance has a uniform prior as shown in the image:

[image: Model description]

I do not know how to add alpha to the model, and then specify the new parameter in the priors...

Answer (score 0):

You would just add `alpha` into your linear predictor and give it a distribution like any of the other parameters. However, `JAGS` parameterizes the Normal distribution as precision instead of variance (precision is just the inverse of the variance).  The model would look something like this instead. Also, you can just use `logit(eta)` instead of applying the inverse logit.

```
mymodel = function(){
  for (i in 1:16){
    y[i] ~ dbin(eta[i], n[i] )
    logit(eta[i]) <- alpha + gamma*x1[i]+beta1*x2[i]+beta2*x3[i]+beta3*x4[i]
  }

  # Prior
  alpha ~ dnorm(0, tau_alpha)
  tau_alpha <- 1 / var_alpha
  var_alpha ~ dunif(0, 10)
  gamma ~ dnorm(0,0.00001) 
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
  beta2 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
  beta3 ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)
}
```